# Remove exception string from complete error message

Tags: java, regex

I have to show error to user but error string has exception class name as well like

> com.company.module.CustomException: Unable to find the user

I want to  substring the full string and want only "Unable to find the user"
Is there any regex which can help me.
Note Exception class is generated on run time.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Why don't you just use `index of ":" + 1` as the start position to create the substring?

Comment: I just want to crop the unwanted class, and this fashion is used in entire project so I cant change the basic code level, just want to cut the string

Comment: @BackSlash well said bro, let me try this. Thanks

Comment: As you asked for regex (not recommended) you can solve it like this: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\:.*"); Matcher m= p.matcher(yourString); m.find(); System.out.println(m.group());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not to do any **string operations like substring or regex to deal with exception messages**, rather the ideal way to handle this is to **use `yourExceptionObj.getMessage()`**, 
    but you need to set the exception message in your `CustomException` class constructor by calling `super(message)`.

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    public CustomException(String message) {
       super(message);
    }

    //add your other code here
}
```

Now, if you call `yourExceptionObj.getMessage()`, you will actually get the message thrown during exception.